# Select list element by name pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, list

I have a list like

```
places <- list(
  'cities-1' = c('Madrid', 'Valencia', 'Barcelona'),
  'countries-1' = c('España', 'Portugal', 'Francia'),
  'cities-2' = c('Alicante', 'San Sebastian', 'Lugo'),
  'countries-2' = c('Italia', 'Grecia', 'Alemania')
)
```

I would like to create a new list with those elements which their name accomplish the pattern 'cities'. If it would be possible, I would like use 'tidyverse' style.

Any help would be appreciated. Regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is easier with `grep` from `base R`.  Get a logical index with `grepl` by checking the `pattern` 'cities' on the `names` of the `list` and then use that to subset the `list` elements

```
places[grepl("cities", names(places))]
```

---

or with `tidyverse`, instead of `grepl`, use `str_detect` (from `stringr`) and `keep` (from `purrr`) the `list` elements that satisfy the condition

```
library(tidyverse)
names(places) %>% 
      str_detect('cities') %>%
      keep(places, .)
```

---

As @Frank mentioned in the comments, a `tbl` or `data.frame` may be more convenient for analysis

```
data_frame(nm = names(places), places) %>% 
     unnest %>% 
     filter(str_detect(nm, "cities"))
```

Or in `base R`

```
subset(stack(places), grepl("cities", ind))
```

Comment: Or make a table instead of a list `data_frame(nm = names(places), places) %>% unnest %>% filter(str_detect(nm, "cities"))`

Comment: Your second example could also be written as `places %>% keep(str_detect(names(.), 'cities'))`, which I'd find a little tidier.